# Javascript: Sort Object by value

Tags: javascript

I have the following object:

```
{1234: "3.05", 1235: "2.03", 1236: "3.05"}
```

I would like to sort them by **value** to get something like this:

```
{1235: "2.03", 1234: "3.05", 1236: "3.05"}
```

I tried:

```
const sortedList = _.orderBy(myList, (value, key) => {
        return value;
      }, ['asc']);
```

The values get sorted but it is only a list of values:

```
{0: "2.03", 1: "3.05", 2: "3.05"}
```

How can I retain the keys?

Comment: You cannot sort an object.

Comment: "Sorting" the keys of an object doesn't make much sense; it's very fragile. If you just want it for presentation you can always sort the object entries however you want with `Object.entries(yourObject).sort()`.

Comment: Objects are not guaranteed order so there are better ways of doing this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order Solutions are really based on what your goal is.

Comment: Objects **are** guaranteed order, and therefore you **can** sort an object. *But*, you can't sort **this** object because it has integer indices.

Comment: numerical keys are sorted by value, if they could be array indices.

Comment: @TylerRoper that's true, and I think it's good that the committee standardized the behavior, but I would still strongly recommend to anyone against building application code that relies on property order to determine behavior. It's just a huge bug magnet.

Comment: @Pointy I don't disagree with you there. I wouldn't suggest using an object for anything you need ordered. I just think that it's important to dispel the now-untrue notion that objects *cannot* be sorted. **To OP:** Long story short, you can't accomplish what you're looking for using a simple object, nor should you try. Throwing "should or shouldn't" out the window, if an object has integer keys (as yours does), they will **always** be sorted ascending. If order is important, consider a `Map`, or even an array of key-value pairs.

Comment: one way to sort object and use its keys is by using Object.entries and sorting values -  Object.entries(obj).sort((a,b) => a[1] - b[1])   ... https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/OexwQY  , As mentioned in above comments sorting object is not possible,and order is not guaranteed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. The only catch is that the output has to be an array in order to guarantee the order of keys.

```js
const input = {1234: "3.05", 1235: "2.03", 1236: "3.05"}

const output = Object.entries(input)
                     .sort(([, v1], [, v2]) => v1 - v2)
                     .map(([key, value]) => ({ [key]: value }))

console.log(output)
```